# How Can I use Zimbra Postfix mail Server for Redmine application

Tags: zimbra

I have Zimbra 8.04 RHEL 64 edition installed & inst working quite fine with Windows server 2003 POP3 mail Server.

BUT I want to know how can I use the Installed Zimbra Server services `EX:- Postfix/Mysql/OpenLDAP` for other applications also.

EX:-  I have Redmine Application installed in the same Server my another question is.

How Can I use Zimbra Postfix mail Server for Redmine application ?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu I did as follows to configure email notifications in Redmine. Zimbra and Redmine installed on the same host:

```
zcat /usr/share/doc/redmine/examples/configuration.yml.example.gz > /etc/redmine/default/configuration.yml
```

Edit then /etc/redmine/default/configuration.yml with your fav editor and find the uncommented smtp configuration. Change it as follows:

```
default:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: your_zimbra_host
      port: 25
      domain: your_mail_domain
```

After this restart Apache (or whatever you're using to serve Redmine) and go to Redmine web interface, Administration > Settings > Email notifications and change them to fit your needs.

This configuration should fit any SMTP server, being it Postfix, Zimbra, or sendmail.